# Learning Simple HTML Google Cloud Run Deployment

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-run

I am trying to use GCP Cloud Run to deploy a Docker image to the web. Using the graphical interface:

1. I Create a Service
2. Enter my image as follows: docker.io/phillymontana/test:v1.0 - no problems here. This image runs  when i build the container on my local machine.

My dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
RUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html

COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY style.css /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I set the Container Port setting at 80 in the UI options.

Thinking my issue was a .conf file I've even included it as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

When I try to Create the deployment I get the following error:
'
Revision 'myapp-00001-c9t' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=80 environment variable.
'

This is just a simple html and css file using an nginx web server.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing. I thought this would be simple. I am testing this out so that I can move on to figuring out how to deploy my react apps.

I am expecting for the deployment to create a url for me and have my application running in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I had spend 2 days trying to find the answer to this problem. The second I post on StackOverflow I come across the following nuance:

If you are like me developing on a Mac with an M1 chip you must put this flag into your dockerfile if you plan to deploy to the cloud (AWS or GCP, etc)-

FROM **--platform=linux/amd64** nginx:latest

That's it! I deployed the same way I had been for days and it worked like a charm.

Stupid GCP.